# Verify date format in textbox entry

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I wish to provide a textbox in excel vba  to enter the date. Permissible date formats are d-m-yy or yyyy, dd-mm-yy or yyyy, d/m/yy or yyyy, dd/mm/yy or yyyy. But the output format should be dd-mm-yyyy. I just don't know where to start. I know how to write the data to the required except worksheet but no idea about this code.Please guide

```
If IsDate(Me.TextBox2.Value) = False Then. 
MsgBox "Enter a valid date format." & vbNewLine _  
& "Valid Date Formats are:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _  
& "D/M/YY" & vbNewLine _  
& "DD/MM/YYYY" & vbNewLine _ & "D-M-YY" & vbNewLine _  
& "DD-MM-YYYY", vbExclamation, "Date Format ERROR"  
TextBox2.Activate  
Exit Sub  
End If 
'This works perfect 
Worksheets("PURCHASE").Range("B" & newrow) = CDate(TextBox2.Text)
Worksheets("PURCHASE").Range("B" & newrow).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

Comment: Use three textboxes, one for day, month and year each. Might save some stress :)! (or a datepicker, but that's not very recommandable imo)

Comment: hi darryl, what have you tried already? can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a VBA [Range.IsDate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function) that attempts to resolve a valid date as true and an invalid date as false.

> In Windows, the range of valid dates is January 1, 100 A.D., through December 31, 9999 A.D.; the ranges vary among operating systems.

That doesn't explain the Excel 1900 date system but it does explain the Excel 1904 date system. Blame [Lotus 1-2-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year_bug) for the inequality.

Whatever algorithm is used in `IsDate`, I can say that I've had marginally more success when using it than a `CDate` conversion over a wide variety of system locales both on the source and target end.

Ultimately I've found the SQL standard YYYYMMDD an efficient storage and delivery method as well as raw long integers. The latter would simply require cell formatting in Excel to show a real human being that the value is a date.

If your code accepts the string date input as verified by CDate or IsDate then you may be transferring a string date into your cell. Dates are numeric and may need to be formatted in order for a human being to see them as dates and not a number like 43453.

```
Worksheets("PURCHASE").Range("B" & newrow) = cdate(TextBox2.Text)
Worksheets("PURCHASE").Range("B" & newrow).numberformat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Use the Edit link under your question then post your code and select the the code and use Ctrl+K.

Comment: @user11413734 You are making nonsense edits to my answer in an attempt to comment on what you think is "wrong on many levels". I wonder whether you have attempted to execute the code as I have, which will show you it does in fact work.

Comment: That is *exactly* the reason why I used that code. Formatting a nonsense date will leave the original string unchanged, thereby indicating that a nonsense date string was entered. `nwdate = TextBox1.Value` tests this. If this is true, `TextBox1.Value` does NOT contain a valid date. Look at my answer again.

Comment: @DarrylCastellino - Please see addendum above.

Comment: @TimStack - While I'll concede that your methodology is sound within the confines of this question, I don't think I'll ever embrace it as a *defacto* method of true date validation. I'll just wish you good luck with it.

Comment: Next time refrain from criticising another user's answer without first validating their functionality, and **especially** refrain from doing this through unnecessary edits on their posts.

Comment: @TimStack - WOW! And I was just coming back to apologize for questioning your methods. Thanks for alleviating me of that task clown.

Comment: Please keep it civil :)

Comment: ... and WOW! again @TimStack. I haven't seen such passive-aggressive crap for several months.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to, after the user entered a string into the textbox, to check whether it is possible to format the date. If not, a nonsense-date has been added and the user can be notified of the issue

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim nwdate As String

    If Len(TextBox1.Value) < 6 Then GoTo falsedate
    nwdate = Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    If nwdate = TextBox1.Value And Format(nwdate, "dd-mmmm-yyyy") = nwdate Then
        GoTo falsedate
    Else
        TextBox1.Value = nwdate
    End If
    Exit Sub
falsedate:
    MsgBox "Enter a valid date before proceeding", vbExclamation, "Error"
    TextBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: @user11413734 this is not "wrong on so many levels". I'll happily invite you to test the code. Formatting `Textbox1.Value` if the textbox does not hold the link will result in *no change*. This will indicate the validity of the entered value

Comment: TextBox2.Text = Format(TextBox1.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
 changes September 6th 2019 written is 6-9-19 to 09-06-1903

Comment: Darryl, I cannot seem to replicate that issue. Try inserting that line before the `Exit Sub` line.

Comment: That if statement checks if the date entered in textbox if it is false. Adding before exit sub would not format the date to dd-mm-yyy if the textbox contained a valid date format

Comment: Yes it would. I'd even simplify the line to `TextBox2.Value = TextBox1.Value` as the value of TextBox 1 is already formatted correctly before the `Exit Sub` line

Comment: Textbox1 is text (Invoice number) and Textbox2 is a date(invoice date)

Comment: Then why would you want to format the value from TextBox1 as a date and paste this to TextBox2? That makes no sense

Comment: If TextBox2 holds the date value and not TextBox1, change all references to TextBox1 in my code to TextBox2

Comment: I tried your method but your code that checks for length of the textbox.value is where it fails as the date if is 10/1/2019 will be 7 so will be false date. The IsDate to check if textbox is a date and then writing Cdate(textbox.text) and setting number format ="dd-mm-yyyy" as suggested by user11413734 does the job for me

Comment: Thank-you @user11413734

Comment: @darrylcastellino "10/1/2019" will NOT return a false date message because of the string length. String lengths shorter than 6 characters are false dates. This string is 9 characters long. Not sure where you're getting 7 from, but that would also be a perfectly fine string length.